# How can I find the source of a memory leak?

Tags: memory

I found a really weird issue using NDSolve`ProcessEquations inside module.

We start by setting HistoryLength to 0. After this we define a function which takes in an integer and creates a Table of stateData Objects of the desired length and returns a list containing a string and the list of stateData objects. To show how much memory the local objects use I make use of the Print[] function.

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
Clear[prepareEquations]
prepareEquations[iMax_] := 
  Module[{stateDataList, output},
    stateDataList = 
    Table[
      First @
        NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y''[t] + y[t] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, {y, y'}, t], 
      {i, 1, iMax}];
    Print["ByteCount stateDataList :", ByteCount[stateDataList]];
    output = {"hello", stateDataList};
    Print["ByteCount output :", ByteCount[output]];
    output
  ];
```

First we want to see how much memory we use before calling the functions.

```
MemoryInUse[]
```

> ```
> 30105504
> ```

Alright, so about 30.1 mb. Now we call the function with an input value of 5000. The function will at the same time print how much memory the local objects use.

```
finalList = prepareEquations[5000];
ByteCount stateDataList :87590968
ByteCount output :87591064
```

So the output takes about 87.6 mb. So we would assume that the total memory used after calling this function would be about `30.1+87.6=117.7` mb. But instead we have

```
MemoryInUse[]
```

> ```
> 164795040
> ```

Which is about 164.8 mb. Hence there seems to vanish about `164.8-117.7=47.1` mb.

If i look into my global context, finalList takes up as much memory as the ByteCount of output. If I change the output to not return the stateDataList by for example `output={"hello",1}`, no memory is leaked. Where does the extra memory go when I return a list of stateData objects?

Notice that local variables `y$1235`, `y$125`, ..., and so on is leaked to the global context. I removed them by

```
Remove /@ Select[Names["Global`*"],StringMatchQ[#1, "y$" ~~ DigitCharacter ..] &];
```

and the memory used after this was

```
MemoryInUse[]
```

> ```
> 164518400
> ```

so they don't seems to have a major impact. If i look into my global context it looks like this

```
Reverse@SortBy[Map[{#, ByteCount@ToExpression[#]} &, Names["Global`*"]], Last] //TableForm
```

> ```
> {"finalList", 87591064},
> {"y", 0},
> {"t", 0},
> {"stateDataList$", 0},
>     {"stateDataList", 0},
>     {"prepareEquations", 0},
>     {"output$", 0},
> {"output", 0},
> {"iMax", 0},
> {"i", 0}
> ```

So the memory leaked doesn't show up here. Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: I get a very similar result, even if I remove the `Module` and the `Print`s. `ClearSystemCache` has no effect. Using `Remove` on `finalList` gives me back most of the memory. Note that the data you generate has a function `Experimental'NumericalFunction` in it. Well.. yeah, undocumented functions..

Comment: Yes, I also tried to Remove the finalList and got back most of the memory. Did you manage to find where the memory was hidden? I guess that there are temporary variables which may take up memory here. When I look into the NDSolve` context there is a lot of temporary variables but none of them take up signficiant space.

Where did you find the `Experimental'NumericalFunction `?

Comment: `finalList[[2,1]]//FullForm` I believe is where I found it. I still don't know where the memory went.

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to the problem above. Suggestions, anyone?

Comment: Maybe you can try to make a more minimal example. Did you manage to find the Experimental'NumericalFunction? If you can update the question a little bit, I will once again be an "active" question and other people might see it.